# Java Configuration for Spring OAuth2 Resource Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I currently have a Resource Server that is configured via the `application.yml` file.  The file contains:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: foo-client
      client-secret: bar
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
      token-info-uri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/check_token
```

Could someone provide an example of configuring this via Spring's Java configuration?  I am having trouble finding examples.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking for the same thing that ran across your question. I was just curious on how it is done more than needing to do it. Anyhow, after a little digging around, I went to the [common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) to see if there was any info and took a look at the [OAuth2ClientProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/OAuth2ClientProperties.java) and [ResourceServerProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/ResourceServerProperties.java) API's and found the settings in both. I assume that you create a bean with the settings in some config file and it should work just like anything else.

I hope that helps you in the right direction!